# css transform scale delay in useEffect

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on a map component and I'm running into a strange issue with about a 2s delay when first clicking the zoom button. I'm trying to use scale() to reduce recalculating pin locations on zoom. I've tried reducing the map image size, adjusting the width of the mapBox instead of scale(), scaling the image itself. All result in a delay. However after the first click of zoom in, there's no delay on zoomIn or zoomOut.

I can see the code instantly update in devTools, and if I edit the css in dev tools their is no delay, so I don't think my image size is causing the delay. Removing the pin's reduces the delay slightly but still there.

What am I missing?

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, use } from 'react';
import maps from '../data/maps.json';
import styles from './MapBox.module.css';

const MapBox = ({ name }) => {
  const [viewportSize, setViewportSize] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });
  const [mapSize, setMapSize] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(1);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  const [boundaries, setBoundaries] = useState({ minX: 0, maxX: 0, minY: 0, maxY: 0 });
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);

  const mapData = maps.find((map) => map.name === name);
  const viewportRef = useRef(null);

  function consolLog() {
    console.log(Object.values(viewportSize));
    console.log(zoom);
  };

  const handleZoomIn = () => {
    setZoom((prevZoom) => Math.min(prevZoom + 1, 10));
    console.log('Zoom In');
  };
  const handleZoomOut = () => {
    setZoom((prevZoom) => Math.max(prevZoom - 1, 1));
    console.log('Zoom Out');
  };

  //Handle Map mouse interactivity
  useEffect(() => {
    const mapViewport = document.getElementById('mapBoxViewport');
    
    const handleMouseDown = () =>  {
      setIsDragging(true);
      console.log('Mouse Down');
    };
    const handleMouseUp = () => {
      setIsDragging(false);
    };
    const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
      console.log('Mouse Move');
    };
    const handleMouseLeave = () => {
      setIsDragging(false);
      console.log('Mouse Leave');
    };

    if (!isDragging) {
      mapViewport.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
    } else {
      mapViewport.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
      mapViewport.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
      mapViewport.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
      mapViewport.addEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
    };

    return () => {
      mapViewport.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
      mapViewport.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);
      mapViewport.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
      mapViewport.removeEventListener('mouseleave', handleMouseLeave);
    };
  }, [isDragging]);

  //Handle Map Zoom
  useEffect(() => {
    const map = document.getElementById('mapBoxMap');

    map.style.transform = `scale(${zoom})`;
    map.style.transition = 'transform 1000ms ease';

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      map.style.transform = `scale(${zoom})`;
      map.style.transition = 'transform 1000ms ease';
    });

  }, [zoom]);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if(!viewportRef.current) return;

    const viewportObserver = new ResizeObserver(() => { 
      if(viewportRef.current.offsetWidth !== viewportSize.width) {
        setViewportSize({
          width: viewportRef.current.offsetWidth,
          height: viewportRef.current.offsetHeight
        });
      };
    });

    viewportObserver.observe(viewportRef.current);

    return () => viewportObserver.disconnect();
    
  }, [viewportRef.current]);

  //console.log(Object.values(viewportSize));
  //console.log(zoom);

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <div>{viewportSize.width}</div>
      <div className={styles.buttons}>
        <button className={styles.zoomButton} onClick={handleZoomIn}>+</button>
        <button className={styles.zoomButton} onClick={handleZoomOut}>-</button>
      </div>
      <div id="mapBoxViewport" className={styles.viewport} ref={viewportRef}>
        <div id="mapBoxMap" className={styles.contents}>
          <img 
            src={mapData.image} 
            alt={`${name}`} 
            className={styles.mapImage} 
            draggable="false" 
          />
          {mapData.secretRooms && mapData.secretRooms.map((room, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            className={styles.pin2}
            style={{ left: room.x, top: room.y }}
          />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapBox;
```

Comment: You are re-rendering the App when using `useEffect` in this way.  So it will take whatever original load time the app takes to originally render, to re-render.

Comment: there is only a delay on the first useEffect re-render, the subsequent rerenders are instant.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was CPU usage maxing out when scaling the images.

I used the performance tab in dev tools to record the zoom action and was able to see the CPU hitting 100% and the zoom action executing when the cpu usage dropped.